# Trying to `db.session.commit()` using SQLalchemy and it throws an IntegrityError

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

### **The problem**

I'm a beginner to Flask and back-end in general and I don't really now any SQL...

I have been fallowing a tutorial on Youtube on creating a flask app and I came across an error when I tried add ad Admin user. I have tried to recreate a basic app and try to narrow down the problem by only creating the Admin Model and trying to put stuff into it and it shows me the same error.

### **My APP**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Admin(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Admin('{self.username}', '{self.password}')"


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    admin = Admin(username='Justas', password='test')
    db.session.add(admin)
    db.session.commit()                              # Error at here
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

### The error

this shows in the terminal when I try to run it `python app.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sarunas\Desktop\test APP\my_app\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1283, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\Sarunas\Desktop\test APP\my_app\env\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 590, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: admin.username

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

...

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: admin.username
[SQL: INSERT INTO admin (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Justas', 'test')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

Comment: Do you get if from the first run, or from the second?

Comment: You've hardcoded the username, but set it unique in your model when creating the table. One has to give.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages indicate that you are trying to create an admin that already exists. You can avoid this by adding a check before creating a new admin;

```
if db.session.query(Admin).filter_by(username='Justas').count() < 1:
admin = Admin(username='Justas', password='test')
db.session.add(admin)
db.session.commit()                              
return 'Hello, World!'
```

Please test it with the above code.